# Does the std::allocator destructor free the memory it has allocated?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, allocator

I'm relatively new to C++'s `std::allocator` and I was wondering whether `std::allocator<T>::~allocator` frees the memory it has allocated.

[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/%7Eallocator) is a link to the docs from cppreference, which I think make it clear why I had to ask the question here.

Comment: The examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) call `traits_t::deallocate()` to free the memory.

Comment: It doesn't remember what memory it has allocated.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not release any allocated memory. `std::allocator` has no state and doesn't keep track of what memory has been allocated.

It is the job of the user to call `std::allocator::deallocate` (typically through `std::allocator_traits::deallocate`) on every previous allocation with `std::allocator::allocate` (and it also doesn't matter through which instance of `std::allocator` these calls happen).